# Algebra - Inequalities - Finding Range of an Expression.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Suppose $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are positive reals with ${a^2}+{b^2}+{c^2}+{d^2}=4$. Find the range of:

$${a^3}+{b^3}+{c^3}+{d^3}$$

Comment: I couldn't slove this problem by myself. It would be a real help if anyone have the answer to this question.

Comment: I am ready to help you. Show please your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Power Mean Inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality), we have
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3}{4}} \geqslant \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{4}} = 1,$$
threfore
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 \geqslant 4.$$
Equality occur when $a=b=c=d=1.$

Because $$4=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \geqslant a^2,$$ we get $a \leqslant 2,$ so $$a^2(a-2) \leqslant 0,$$ or $$a^3 \leqslant 2a^2,$$ thefore
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 \leqslant 2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) = 2 \cdot 4 = 8.$$
Equality occur when $a=2,\,b=c=d=0$ (not occur because $a,\,b,\,c,\,d$ are positive reals), so
$$4 \leqslant a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 < 8.$$